# Browser extension: prevent script from being executed

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, mutation-observers

I tried to use a `MutationObserver` in a user script to get a "script added" event and simply removed the script and src attributes. I also tried to put the mutation observer into the webpage as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/insert-code-into-the-page-context-using-a-content-script). Script elements in the body are still executed, despite removing the attributes. I tested this on Firefox.

Comment: MutationObserver is asynchronous so it runs after the script has already executed. In Firefox you can use onbeforescriptexecute and call preventDefault inside, [example](/a/23943740).

Comment: Just tested it and it works flawlessly, thank you @wOxxOm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onbeforescriptexecute` makes things easier as @wOxxOm said. I didn't have to care when if head/body exists to listen for muration changes.